# Taylor series like polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, induction

Let $U$ be an open subset of $R^n$ and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function and $x\in U$ such that in a small neighbourhood of $x$ and for $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R^b}$ sufficiently small we have the following:

$$\begin{equation} 
f(x+ \epsilon) = \sum\limits_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_{\alpha}\epsilon^{\alpha} + g(\epsilon)  \\
f(x+ \epsilon) = \sum\limits_{|\alpha| \leq k} b_{\alpha}\epsilon^{\alpha} + h(\epsilon)
\end{equation}$$

where $\alpha \in \mathbb{N_0}^n$ a multiindex, $k$ a natural number, $g$ and $h$ functions such that $\lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(\epsilon)}{||\epsilon||^k} = \lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{h(\epsilon)}{||\epsilon||^k}  = 0$.

My goal is to prove that for all $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\leq k$ it holds that:

$a_{\alpha}$ = $b_{\alpha}$ but I am very confused my the multiindex notation because I am not sure how the limits would behave since I don't know that $f$ is differenctiable.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Presumably this is a homework question? If so, it would help to know what course you're taking. Anyway, here are two strategic hints: (i) In analysis (and algebra, for that matter), it's usually easier to prove $X - Y = 0$ than to prove $X = Y$ directly. (ii) Write out your expansion explicitly for $k=0$ and for $k=1$; can you identify any coefficients $a_\alpha$ in terms of $f$?

Comment: Yes, it is related to an analysis homework I have. This is how I started but for k =1, 2, 3 is ok however I get a bit messy in my arguments for k larger than that so I assume I am missing the big picture.

Comment: I actually think I don't understand what the problem actually requires. What is k for example?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a multi-index of "length" $k$, then $\epsilon^\alpha$ is a monomial of degree $k$. For instance, if $n = 3$ (i.e., you have a function of three variables), the general multi-index is $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$, its length is $k=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3$, and $\epsilon^\alpha=\epsilon_1^{\alpha_1}\epsilon_2^{\alpha_2}\epsilon_3^{\alpha_3}$. More particularly, $\alpha=(3,5,2)$ has length $k=10$, and $\epsilon^\alpha=\epsilon_1^3\epsilon_2^5\epsilon_3^2$.

Comment: The whole proof is still unclear for me even if for small values I manage to do it . Could you help me further?

Comment: Could I always choose $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ to be 0 for example and prove that the remaining will result in a coefficient of 0 and so on?

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest trying small values of $n$ (the number of variables) and $k$ (the degree of differentiability) to develop a feel of what's being asked. For example, is your claim comprehensible and apparent when $n = 1$? (It asserts uniqueness of the Taylor polynomial.) If that's fine, what about $n = 2$ and $k = 1$; can you prove your assertion in detail in this case? If not, why not?